# Disabeling Copy/paste from my form using java script

Tags: javascript, html

i am searching for a way to disable copy and paste from my form using javascrip. 
i dont want the user to be able to past anything to the form or copying anything.
help please.

Comment: This is ultimately futile. The user can always turn off javascript and copy and paste to his heart's content.

Comment: a restricted user is not a happy user ..

Comment: @Tyler McHenry What if data is rendered through javascript

Comment: @Adeel - Doesn't matter.  I can visit your site with JS on, wait for the data to render and then turn it off.  The rendered content does not magically disappear when I turn of JS.

Comment: You're asking the wrong question.

If you don't want the user to be able to copy stuff from your form, don't put the information online.  The user has downloaded this info, it's on his machine now.  He can get it from the cache if he would want to.  Heck, if he was patient he could copy it by hand.

There's no waterproof way to do this, so don't try.

Answer (score 3):

You will be modifying the way the user expects basic functionality to work.  Why do you not want them to copy or paste anything?  I heavily advise against building that into your solution.

Also have you thought about people with Javascript disabled?

Comment: no nothing would be change .. but i dont want the users to paste data into the form that they are filling or for example if there is confirm your email box  dont want them to be able to copy this information from the first txtbox and paste in the second

Comment: That is just silly, think about how many sites manage without such limitations in their registration forms.

Comment: The confirm email box really grates me, because you can see what you type.  It makes sense for passwords, because you can't see what you type.  Also, think about why someone would copy + paste their email in, probably because they are 100% sure they entered it correctly the first time!  I do this all the time.  You are going to irritate a lot of users if you block that functionality.

Comment: Well put. I use a password manager/generator application for many of my passwords. This means that I have no idea what most of my passwords are, and there's no way I'm going to type in a 20-30 character long randomly generated password twice!

Answer (score 0):

Just add these attributes to the textbox

```
ondragstart=”return false” onselectstart=”return false”
```

Comment: This still doesn't prevent copying using the keyboard.